# how to know how many words are in a string in mips

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I have the string "Hello world" in A and I want to know how many words make A and that I save that number in D like the photo below. how can I do it?

A → "Hello World"

D → 2

Comment: You haven't defined exactly what you think counts as a "word". That is, where does a word begin and end? Once you have decided the rules for that, write a loop that iterates over your string and count the number of times that a word begins according to your rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
.text
main:
    # prompt user for string
    la $a0 prompt
    li $v0 4
    syscall

    # get string
    la $a0 A 
    li $a1 50   # maximum size of string 
    li $v0 8
    syscall

    move $s0 $a0    # incrementable pointer to buf
    li   $s1,0      

li $t3,0

      
loop:
    # t1 = *(A++) and exit if '\0' or '\n'
    lb $t1 ($s0)    # t1 = *A
    
    beqz $t1 end    # break if '\0'
    beq $t1 10 end  # break if '\n'

    add $s0,$s0,1
    beq $t1,32,is_space  # if current char is space jump to is_space
    li $t3,1   # the current char isn't space so  set $t3 to 1
    j loop

is_space:
    beq  $t3,$zero, loop  # if $t3 == 0 it means only spaces detected at this moment
    li $t3,0              # else char present before space, set $t3 to 0
    addi $s1,$s1,1        # +1 word
    j loop
end: 
    beq  $t3,$zero, print_result  
    li $t3,0
    addi $s1,$s1,1
    # display number of words
print_result:      
    move $a0 $s1
    li $v0 1
    syscall
    
    # exit program
    li $v0 10
    syscall

.data
A: .space 50   # length of desired string
D: .word -1      # number of words
prompt: .asciiz "Input a string : "
```

Comment: This will count spaces between words + 1, so "Hello World" -> 2 and "Hello  World" -> 3.  Maybe also redo trim after finding a space.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have you tested this code?

Comment: It stood to reason by review, but yes, I did run it to find that Hello space space World counts 3.